# The patient/patients in question in each/both of these scenarios

Tags: grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis

Which of the following variations is correct/prefered. First, should "patient" be singular or plural? Related to that, should I use "both of" or "each of"?

> The patient/patients in question in each/both of these scenarios has/have the required knowledge.

Sine "both" has with it a sense of plurality, using singular (patient) seems to me to be inconsistent with it. Related to this point, "scenarios" is plural.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're assuming the presence of the word *both* and asking about agreement with the rest (opening *vs* closing paragraph of the question). You also haven't said whether you have one patient in total or if you have more than one, whether there's only one in each scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is insufficient context provided to allow for a conclusive answer; however, the noun 'patient/patients' and the verb 'has/have' must agree in number.

If you are writing about multiple scenarios, each of which has one patient involved, I would write *The patient in question in each of these scenarios has required knowledge.*

If you are writing about two scenarios using the same single patient, I would write *The patient in question in both of these scenarios has required knowledge.*

If you are writing about multiple scenarios, one or more of which have multiple patients, but not the same set of patients, I would write *The patients in question in each of these scenarios have required knowledge.* This is also the usage even if one or more (but not all) of the scenarios have single patients.

If you are writing about two scenarios using the same group of patients, I would write *The patients in question in both of these scenarios have required knowledge.*